# Submit a Form using PUT instead of POST

Tags: php, symfony

I have a controller which processes form submission from AJAX requests. I don't want to repeat myself, so I put the form processing code in a method:

```
// Should process POST request
public function create(Request $request)
{
    return $this->processEdit($request);
}

// Should process PUT request
public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $entity = $this->findEntity($id); // custom method

    if (!$entity)
        return $this->myCustomErrorResponse();

    return $this->processEdit($request, $entity);
}

private function processEdit(Request $request, Entity $entity = null)
{
    $form = $this->createForm('my_entity', $entity);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Handle invalid form
    }

    return $response;
}
```

I have the following two routes:

```
ajax_create:
    pattern: /
    defaults: { _controller: 'MyBundle:Ajax:create' }
    methods: [ POST ]

ajax_update:
    pattern: /{id}
    defaults: { _controller: 'MyBundle:Ajax:update' }
    methods: [ PUT ]
    requirements:
        id: \d+
```

However, when I submit the form via AJAX, it will not accept `PUT` request and return form is not valid without any form error message. If I alter the controller code abit,

```
$form = $this->createForm('my_entity', $entity, array(
    'method' => 'PUT',
));
```

... it will process `PUT` request but not `POST` request.

I wondered which part of Symfony2 does the HTTP method checking for a form so I tried to look for the answer in the source code, but I couldn't find a clue. Could any of you share your knowledge please?

Another question, is there a way to bypass HTTP method checking? I'm currently passing `$method` to the method shown above.

Thank you very much.

---

Update:

To make my question clearer, my Symfony2 application routes the request (both POST and PUT) to the correct controller method.

I mentioned the altered code above, here it is:

```
// Should process POST request
public function create(Request $request)
{
    return $this->processEdit($request);
}

// Should process PUT request
public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $entity = $this->findEntity($id); // custom method

    if (!$entity)
        return $this->myCustomErrorResponse();

    return $this->processEdit($request, 'PUT', $entity);
}

private function processEdit(Request $request, $method = 'POST', Entity $entity = null)
{
    $form = $this->createForm('my_entity', $entity, array(
        'method' => $method,
    ));

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Handle invalid form
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a couple of (hopefully) helpful notes:

First things first, you can get the submit method from the Request object, no need to pass it separately:

[getMethod()](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_getMethod)

Secondly, I think I found the part of the code you were looking for. First off, if you check the `handleRequest` call in the Symfony [Form](https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/Form.php#L486) class, you can see it calls the `handleRequest` from the `RequestHandler` class situated in the config (check `FormConfigInterface` class). I'm guessing that the correct implementation of the `RequestHandlerInterface` is [NativeRequestHandler](https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/NativeRequestHandler.php#L39). You can see there on the line [48](https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/NativeRequestHandler.php#L48) the check for the equality of request methods.

Now, to handle this, you might be able to set the form's FormConfigInterface to a custom value, where you crafted the RequestHandler to your own implementation. If the `NativeRequestHandler` is defined as a service, then you're in luck (currently I don't have access to the list of services). Just switch the class to point to your own implementation.

Having said all this, I think form types check is there for a reason. You should handle your form submit types separately as you are doing now. Also, using POST for inserting **and** editing is quite a good solution. The simpler the better, less chance of introducing new bugs!

Comment: Hey there. Yesterday I was implementing another similar form and I suddenly realized that I could have used `Request::getMethod()`! Anyway, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

**[EDIT 2014-05-23]** I have entirely modified my first answer as it was a "dirty hack".

I had exactly the same issue (and almost the same code). I have read the answers here and I found a major problem in my own code, I forgot to modify the `/web/app.php` files to enable by default the `HttpMethodParameterOverride` parameters. ([It's a change introduced in Symfony2.2](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/commit/1970b831f8843a5cf551e9d88404cb62f21b90f9))

Now everything works as expected using the `handleRequest()` function:

- The create action uses a *POST* query.
- The edit action uses a *PUT* query.
- The delete action uses a *DELETE* query.

I don't need to modify the `RequestHandler` configuration as suggested in the accepted answer.

Now the code looks like this:

```
/**
 * Fruits CRUD service controller.
 *
 * @Route("/services/fruits")
 */
class FruitsController extends Controller
{
    // ...

/**
 * Create a fruit.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @Rest\Post("", name="backend_fruits_create")
 *
 * @return View|array
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    return $this->processForm($request, new Fruit());
}

/**
 * Edit a fruit.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Fruit   $fruit
 *
 * @Rest\Put("/{id}", name="backend_fruits_edit", requirements={"id" = "\d+"})
 * @throws HttpException
 *
 * ## DEV FORM ##
 * @Rest\Get("/edit/{id}", name="backend_fruits_edit_dev", requirements={"id" = "\d+"})
 * @Rest\View
 * ## DEV FORM ##
 *
 * @return View|array
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, Fruit $fruit)
{
    return $this->processForm($request, $fruit);
}

/**
 * Delete a fruit.
 *
 * @param Fruit $fruit
 *
 * @Rest\Delete("/{id}", name="backend_fruits_delete")
 * @throws HttpException
 *
 * @return View
 */
public function deleteAction(Fruit $fruit)
{
    $fruit->delete();

    return $this->responseHelper->createSuccessResponse(
        $fruit->getTree()->getFruits(),
        Response::HTTP_ACCEPTED
    );
}

/**
 * Form handling.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Fruit   $fruit
 *
 * @return View|array
 */
protected function processForm(Request $request, Fruit $fruit)
{
    list($statusCode, $httpMethod, $action) = $this->getActionParameters($fruit);

    $form = $this->createForm(
        new FruitType(), $fruit,
        array('action' => $action, 'method' => $httpMethod)
    );

    if (in_array($request->getMethod(), array('POST', 'PUT'))) {
        if (!$form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {

            return $this->responseHelper->createErrorResponse($form);
        }
        $form->getData()->save();

        return $this->responseHelper->createSuccessResponse($form->getData(), $statusCode);
    }

    return compact('form');
}

/**
 * Set the form and action parameters depending on the REST action.
 *
 * @param Fruit $fruit
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getActionParameters(Fruit $fruit)
{
    if ($fruit->isNew()) {
        $statusCode = Response::HTTP_CREATED;
        $httpMethod = 'POST';
        $action = $this->generateUrl('backend_fruits_create');
    } else {
        $statusCode = Response::HTTP_OK;
        $httpMethod = 'PUT';
        $action = $this->generateUrl('backend_fruits_edit', array('id' => $fruit->getId()));
    }

    return array($statusCode, $httpMethod, $action);
}
```

*Note*: The form type is bound to a model entity.

*Note2*: As you can see, I have an additional GET route. It is useful when developing as I can debug my form in my browser. As this a service constroller, I will delete the related code when finised; the route and in the `processForm` function, no need to test the method and to return the form anymore.

```
/**
 * Form handling.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Fruit   $fruit
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function processForm(Request $request, Fruit $fruit)
{
    list($statusCode, $httpMethod, $action) = $this->getActionParameters($fruit);

    $form = $this->createForm(
        new FruitType(), $fruit,
        array('action' => $action, 'method' => $httpMethod)
    );

    if (!$form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
        return $this->responseHelper->createErrorResponse($form);
    }
    $form->getData()->save();

    return $this->responseHelper->createSuccessResponse($form->getData(), $statusCode);
}
```

*Note3*: The response helper just creates a custom `View` response object with the [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle).

More about REST and Symfony2:

- [REST APIs with Symfony2: The Right Way](http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/)
- [REST APIs made easy with Symfony2](https://speakerdeck.com/gordalina/rest-apis-made-easy-with-symfony2)

Comment: I'm sorry for replying so late. The project has moved to the next step and I'll test your solution once I have the time to refactor the old code. Will try to do it asap! Thank you.

Comment: Hi, your answer looks good but I have found a better way of handling this. See the marked answer. Thank you.